# Cocos2D: moveBy undeclared?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, action

I tried looking this up, but could not find anything relevant, but I think it's a simple problem.  I've been learning Cocos2D, and now all of the sudden it's saying moveBy is undeclared when I try to build my file.  The same goes for the other actions.

I'm just simply doing

```
        id animation = [MoveBy actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(-100, 0)];
    [eggMan runAction: animation];
```

Is there anything simple I forgot to import maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCMoveBy is what you want, rather than MoveBy

Comment: Ugh.. I was following a tutorial and it said MoveBy. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user586006 They we're probably using an older version of Cocos which didn't have the "CC" prefixes.